# How does ELB during auto scalling updates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

During rolling updates in ASG . There could be possibilities that certain number of instances could have latest code and the other may have the old . So in this case , how does the ELB behaves ? . Will it share traffic only to newly formed instances or it will share the load equally ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the deployment strategy you choose to use.

**In Place Deployment:**
If your application/APIs can accept partial changes during deployment, you may choose to deploy upgrades to each instances or certain instances at a time until all instances are updated.

**Blue Green Deployments:**
You deploy updates to a completely different set of instances which are not live, rollout the updates and switch these new instances in the ELB.

These are fairly generic strategies but are available out of the box using AWS CodeDeploy.